# How to find $x_n$ from $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{1-a+a x_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $n\geq 0$ let $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{1-a+a x_n}$, where $a\in (0,1)$.

I would like to know if it is possible to express $x_n$ as a function of $a$ and $x_0$ for all $n\geq0$.

Comment: Add more details...what you tried?

Comment: What is p0? Explain

Comment: The `RSolve[x[n+1]==x[n]/(1-a+a x[n]),x[n],n]` command in Mathematica yields $$x_n=-\frac{a-1}{1-(1-a)^n-a+a(1-a)^n+C(1-a)^n},$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: @furyo Perhaps you meant $x_0$ instead of $p_0?$

Comment: Change: the command `Simplify[RSolve[{x[n+1]==x[n]/(1-a+a x[n]),x[0]==x0},x[n],n]]` in Mathematica yields $$x_n=\frac{x_0}{(1-a)^n+x_0-x_0(1-a)^n}.$$

Comment: Welcome to MES! I changed your title so that it better reflects your question. It is always better to provide a more self-contained one. Also, it is even better (and is highly recommend) to provide your own ideas, attempts or contexts. Finally, have you ever heard of fractional linear transformation?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Not sure a naked formula helps much the OP's *mathematical understanding*... Of course, one could reverse engineer the formula to understand where it comes from, but this requires more mathematical maturity than what we can guess the OP possesses.

Comment: @Did: Only posting it as a check for answers, for correctness.

Comment: Outline: you're iterating the projective linear function in $PGL(1)$ represented by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ a & 1-a \end{bmatrix}$ and if you diagonalize that matrix you can then find its powers.  (And since that matrix is lower triangular it's particularly easy to diagonalize.)

Answer (score 6):

Note that $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}=\frac{1-a}{x_n}+a$$ which implies that $$\frac1{x_{n+1}}-1=(1-a)\left(\frac1{x_n}-1\right)$$ hence $$\frac1{x_n}-1=(1-a)^n\left(\frac1{x_0}-1\right)$$ from which an explicit formula for $x_n$ in terms of $n$, $a$ and $x_0$ follows.

(Of course, there is some well known theory behind all this...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please tell me the name of this famous theory?

Comment: The study of homographies.